# Read in Python with csv.reader a file with two different delimiter in the same file

Tags: python, mysql, csv

I want to import a file from MySQL to python but there are two type of delimiters in the same file, on the same line.

For example:

```
FIELDA_FIELDB_FIELDC; FILEDD; FIELDE; FIELDF
```

I can split with `_` or `;` but cant find how to do both.

I have tried

```
csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';' and '_')
csv_data = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=';' or'_')
```

I have also tried using csv.sniffer.

But only one delimiter is used each time.

How should i do ?

Comment: The obvious answer is to change the source of the file so it produces a file in the correct format - instead of fixing a broken file after that fact. But I assume you can't do that?

Comment: I can i get the file from an FTP before inserting them into my DB .; so i can correct the file first i guess. I was hoping for a single step way

Answer (score 1):

CSV files can only have one delimiter, so your approach can't work. If you can't fix the broken file, you can read it in two steps (assuming Python 2):

```
csv_data = []
with open("file.csv", "rb") as csvfile:
    reader = csv.reader(csvfile, delimiter=";")
    for row in reader:
        new = []
        for item in row:
            new.extend(item.split("_"))
        csv_data.append(new)
```

That solution is of course naive to things like escaped `_` delimiters etc., but it might work as intended for you.

Comment: What will be better and faster ?
Should i replace the '_' delimiter before to have a clean CSV ?
Or use your method ?